# how to send an event to eventbridge in aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

Hi I have been assigned a task to send an event to eventbridge, I want to send the event pattern with customized values, I want to get these values out of Lambda, any help could be appreciated.

Comment: In what language are you required to do this?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sample-eventbridge-custom-event.html,https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Nv-Gejpkhc

Comment: java @AllanChua

Comment: mentioned url is not working @JatinMehrotra

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sample-eventbridge-custom-event.html, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Nv-Gejpkhc

Answer (score 0):

You can go to `Amazon EventBridge -> rule` and create one.In `Define pattern` you can choose `Event pattern` as it is what you want. Here you can select `Pre-defined pattern by service` and select the service(in your case probably a lambda) or you can choose `Custom pattern` where you can give your own pattern(in JSON).
Now you can invoke a target in `Select targets`, maybe an sns. Here you can get the values out of lambda by choosing `Input transformer` e.g (`{"Name":"$.detail.InstanceID"}`).
You can read further about this [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/EventTypes.html).

Comment: Thanks @Riz seems helpful..

Answer (score 0):

I have deployed a [generic webhook](https://serverlessrepo.aws.amazon.com/applications/arn:aws:serverlessrepo:us-east-1:721177882564:applications%7Egeneric-webhook-to-eventbridge) which points to my custom eventbridge bus. On deployment of generic webhook, I get an API gateway endpoint to which i can send POST requests.